# Is there any connection between "redd" (tidy) and "riddle" (sieve)?

Tags: etymology

Fishermen use "redd" for a trout preparing a stream bed for spawning. Is the word connected to "riddle" (sieve) if you go back far enough?

The is no reference to the the above meaning of ***[redd](https://www.etymonline.com/word/redd)*** in Etymonline.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In order to add some background and context to an interesting question here is a link to the lifecycle of the trout -----> http://www.wildtrout.org/content/trout-lifecycle And here is a link regarding 'riddle' (sieve). ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddle_(tool)

Answer (score 1):

The AHD says that the origin of redd in the fishing sense is unknown, while riddle has a more clear origin from Old English “hriddel”:

[redd](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/redd) 
n.

> A spawning nest made by a fish, especially a salmon or trout.
>   [Origin unknown.]

According to [Random House Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/redd), redd in fishing:

> was 
>   first recorded in 1640-50; origin uncertain

and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/redd)  says:

> Word origin of 'redd'
>    (originally: spawn): of obscure origin

[Riddle](https://www.etymonline.com/word/riddle):

> "coarse sieve," mid-14c., alteration of late Old English hriddel, dissimilated from hridder, from Proto-Germanic *hrida- (source also of German Reiter), from PIE root *krei- "to sieve" (source also of Latin cribrum "sieve, riddle," Greek krinein "to separate, distinguish, decide").

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **'redd'**, the name for the gravel surround with which a trout protects its eggs, is related to **'rud'** and **'roud**' which are both to do with spawning.

The words do not seem to relate either to the gravel used for the trout's redd or to any feature of fishing. The words seem to be solely connected to the act of spawning.

> **Redd** - Etymology: Origin unknown. Apparently related to **rud** n.3 and **roud** n....
>
> **Rud** : 1. The act of spawning. Cf. roud n. Obs.
>
> **Roud** : The act of spawning; to be "on the roud": to spawn. Compare roud v.   and rud n.3 1.

([OED - Redd](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/160190?rskey=owOrw6&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid))
([OED - Rud](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168468#eid24742897))
([OED-Roud](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167828#eid24992389))

---

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/165625#eid25297172) also has a reference to 'ridder' (connected to 'riddle' which is related to the act of sieving) :

> :In quot. **c1400** at α. : **a kind of fishing net.**

But neither the word 'riddle' nor its counterpart 'ridder' seem to be the origin of 'redd', despite the fishing association.

---

The first mention of **'redd'** according to the OED citation is :

> 1808   J. Jamieson Etymol. Dict. Sc. Lang. at Red, Redd   With their snouts they form a hollow in the bed of the river, generally so deep, that, when lying in it, their backs are rather below the level of the bed. This is called the **redd.**

'**Rod**' or '**rud**' according to its regional variations ("Sc. and Eng. regional north") is much earlier :

> 1496   in Proc. Orkney Antiquarian Soc. (1925) 3 52   Twiching the bigging of ane myll..on the rod water benewth the said Williame.